# Wxpython gui for task scheduler

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I'am asked to develop a GUI similar to a trigger window in task scheduler.I am trying my best to do it and i am stuck in creating multiple panels in a single frame.Below is the snapshot of how my GUI supposed to look like.Please help me out.

[image: task scheduler]

Comment: If "creating multiple panels in a single frame" is a problem, show us basic simple example of how you tried to put multiple panels in a single frame and how it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the scheduler window i have created using wxpython.

```
class SchedulerWindow(wx.Frame):
""" This generates the GUI for Setting Window"""
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title="Scheduler", style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER ^ wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX, size=(600,500))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)
        font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        self.field = wx.TextCtrl(panel,pos=(65,20),size=(400,20))
        field_lbl=wx.StaticText(panel,-1, label='Name:', pos=(20,20))
        field_lbl.SetFont(font)
        line = wx.StaticLine(panel,pos=(0,50), size=(600,1))
        #sizer.Add(line, pos=(1,30), span=(1, 5),flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
        Box=wx.StaticBox(panel,label='Settings',size=(565,200),pos=(15,60))
        Box1=wx.StaticBox(panel,label='',size=(430,120),pos=(120,120))
        boxsizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(Box, wx.VERTICAL)
        boxsizer.Add(wx.RadioButton(panel,label="One time",pos=(25,90)),flag=wx.LEFT|wx.TOP, border=5)
        boxsizer.Add(wx.RadioButton(panel,label="Daily",pos=(25,110)),flag=wx.LEFT|wx.TOP, border=5)
        boxsizer.Add(wx.RadioButton(panel,label="Weekly",pos=(25,130)),flag=wx.LEFT|wx.TOP, border=5)
        boxsizer.Add(wx.RadioButton(panel,label="Monthly",pos=(25,150)),flag=wx.LEFT|wx.TOP, border=5)
        sizer.Add(boxsizer,pos=(5,10) ,span=(1, 5), 
                 flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.TOP|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT , border=10)
        wx.StaticLine(panel, pos=(100,90), size=(1,100))
        start=wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'Start Date:', pos=(120,90))
        Time=wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'Start Time:', pos=(350, 90))
        start.SetFont(font)
        Time.SetFont(font)
        Box2=wx.StaticBox(panel,label='Advance Settings',size=(565,200),pos=(15,280))
        boxsizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(Box2, wx.VERTICAL)
        boxsizer.Add(wx.CheckBox(panel, -1,'Repeat task every', pos=(20,300),size=(200,25)))
```

I would want to show the time in 'start time:' textctrl. I tried using TimePickerCtrl,but couldn't make it.I used 'DateCtrl' and Calenderdialog to show up the calender in 'Start date:' textctrl. Looking forward for good suggestion with example.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I rarely see the need to put multiple panels inside a frame unless I am doing a wx.Notebook. Perhaps that is what you are looking for. The wx.Notebook is easy to use and there are a bunch of other "book" controls included in wxPython. Here are a couple of links:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/Simple%20wx.Notebook%20Example
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/18/wxpython-how-to-programmatically-change-wx-notebook-pages/
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/03/the-book-controls-of-wxpython-part-1-of-2/

If you really do want multiple panels in your frame, is that for organizing the controls and their layout? I would just use sizers instead. Sizers give you a lot more flexibility. Here's some info on that:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/UsingSizers
- http://zetcode.com/wxpython/layout/
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/05/18/a-wxpython-sizers-tutorial/

And in case you meant that you want to know how to switch between panels, I've got you covered: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/16/wxpython-how-to-switch-between-panels/

Answer (score 0):

Use sizers to layout the position of the controls Ive drawn on the picture approximately  where the sizer would be.

blue = vertical.

green = horizontal.

[image]