# Execute script in background "from" Python 3 programmatically, on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, cron, wxpython

Is possible to launch a script in background FROM ANOTHER PYTHON SCRIPT?

I have one script: awesome.py .This must be executed every minute

But it must be launched from a UI python script (miniApp.py) on click button, this is the function:

```
def startScript(self,e)
    //code to launch awesome.py script in background and repeat every minute
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wxpython gui for task scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964223/wxpython-gui-for-task-scheduler)

Comment: use `threading`

Comment: Related: [calling a python script on button click using python and tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852465/calling-a-python-script-on-button-click-using-python-and-tkinter), [Run script from GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938071/run-script-from-gui)